# how to link math library when building bare metal application with custom linker script

Tags: assembly, compilation, linker, riscv, bare-metal

I am building a RISC-V cpu core, and i am trying to build some C code for it. I have some basic code compiling and linking the way i want and working just fine, for example this:

```
asm("li sp, 0x390");
asm("li s0, 0x390");
asm("li ra, 0");

int main(void){
        char *memptr = 0 ;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                *(memptr + i) = i;
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                       sum += *(memptr + i);
        *((int*)0xC) = sum;

        asm("lw x31, 0xc(x0)");


}
```

and compile/link with these commands:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -nostartfiles -nostdlib -mno-relax -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -c main.c
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -nostartfiles -nostdlib -march=rv32i -melf32lriscv -o main -T link.ld main.o
```

my linker script is the following:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )
ENTRY(main)

MEMORY
{
        progmem (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 8K
        ram (!rx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

SECTIONS
{
        .text : {
                main.o(.text)
        } > progmem


        .data : {
                main.o(.rodata)
                main.o(.data)
                main.o(.sdata)
                main.o(.bss)
        } > ram
}
```

With this setup, i get the results i want no problem. I get my text section (which i put in the program memory), and i get the data section with all of the subsections put in there and load it straight into ram (it works for what im doing right now).

The problems begin when i try to use floating point addition:

```
asm("li sp, 0x390");
asm("li s0, 0x390");
asm("li ra, 0");

float a = 1.7;
float b = 0.7;

int main(void){
        int *memptr = (int*)0x8;
        float c = a - b;

}
```

trying to link after compilation results in this error:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -nostartfiles -march=rv32i -melf32lriscv -o main -T link.ld main.o
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `__subsf3'
```

I can see in the assembly file (using gcc -S option) that there is an instruction **call   __subsf3**, but there is no such label anywhere in the .text section. I believe i have to somehow link the math library for this to work, so i have tried adding **#include "math.h"**, and then adding various flags to the **ld** command like "-lc", "-lgcc", "-lm", but it results in these errors:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: cannot find -lc
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: cannot find -lgcc
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: cannot find -lm
```

By trial and error i have managed to come up with this

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -nostartfiles -mno-relax -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -Wl,-emain -lm main.c -o main
```

which almost does what i want, but does not use my link script. if i add **-Wl,link.ld** then it again doesnt work, giving out errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.1.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: main.o:(.sdata+0x0): multiple definition of `a'; /tmp/cc0LmWB4.o:(.sdata+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.1.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: main.o:(.sdata+0x4): multiple definition of `b'; /tmp/cc0LmWB4.o:(.sdata+0x4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.1.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xc): multiple definition of `main'; /tmp/cc0LmWB4.o:main.c:(.text+0xc): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.1.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.sdata'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me what im doing wrong, and how i should actually go about building the code using the floating point math above for bare metal RISC-V, and get ld to add the math functions in my .text section.

Comment: did you try using gcc to link the program, instead of calling ld directly?  Sometimes it knows where to find the right libraries..

Comment: `-nostartfiles -nostdlib` aren't `ld` options.  It will parse them as single-letter options like `-n -o startfiles` `-n -o stdlib`.  A later `-o` option overrides the two earlier output-file name options.

Comment: Probably you want to statically link `libm.a`.  So use `-lm` when statically linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that gcc is not a linker it is a compiler, but in the gnu world gcc knows where it is (from a directory and relative paths perspective).  Ld is a linker but doesn't know where it is (typical use case (by design) it relies on gcc to pass the library path to it) so...

bootstrap.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    lui x2,0x20010
    jal notmain
    j .
```

notmain.c

```
unsigned int abcd = 5;

float fun ( float a, float b)
{
    return(a+b);
}

int notmain ( void )
{
    return(0);
}
```

memmap

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 8K
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ram
}
```

One way:

```
riscv32-none-elf-as --warn -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 bootstrap.s -o bootstrap.o
riscv32-none-elf-gcc -Wall -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
riscv32-none-elf-ld -T memmap bootstrap.o notmain.o -lgcc -L /opt/gnuriscv32/lib/gcc/riscv32-none-elf/9.1.0/rv32i/ilp32 -o notmain.elf
riscv32-none-elf-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.bin 
riscv32-none-elf-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
```

gives

```
10000000 <_start>:
10000000:   20010137            lui x2,0x20010
10000004:   020000ef            jal x1,10000024 <notmain>
10000008:   0000006f            j   10000008 <_start+0x8>

1000000c <fun>:
1000000c:   ff010113            addi    x2,x2,-16 # 2000fff0 <abcd+0xfff0>
10000010:   00112623            sw  x1,12(x2)
10000014:   018000ef            jal x1,1000002c <__addsf3>
10000018:   00c12083            lw  x1,12(x2)
1000001c:   01010113            addi    x2,x2,16
10000020:   00008067            ret

10000024 <notmain>:
10000024:   00000513            li  x10,0
10000028:   00008067            ret

1000002c <__addsf3>:
1000002c:   008006b7            lui x13,0x800
10000030:   ff010113            addi    x2,x2,-16
10000034:   01755713            srli    x14,x10,0x17

...


20000000 <abcd>:
20000000:   0005
    ...
```

equally distasteful:

```
riscv32-none-elf-as --warn -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 bootstrap.s -o bootstrap.o
riscv32-none-elf-gcc -Wall -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
riscv32-none-elf-gcc -Wall -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -Xlinker -T -Xlinker memmap bootstrap.o notmain.o -lgcc -o notmain.elf
riscv32-none-elf-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.bin 
riscv32-none-elf-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
```

gives

```
10000000 <_start>:
10000000:   20010137            lui x2,0x20010
10000004:   020000ef            jal x1,10000024 <notmain>
10000008:   0000006f            j   10000008 <_start+0x8>

1000000c <fun>:
1000000c:   ff010113            addi    x2,x2,-16 # 2000fff0 <abcd+0xfff0>
10000010:   00112623            sw  x1,12(x2)
10000014:   018000ef            jal x1,1000002c <__addsf3>
10000018:   00c12083            lw  x1,12(x2)
1000001c:   01010113            addi    x2,x2,16
10000020:   00008067            ret

10000024 <notmain>:
10000024:   00000513            li  x10,0
10000028:   00008067            ret

1000002c <__addsf3>:
1000002c:   008006b7            lui x13,0x800
10000030:   ff010113            addi    x2,x2,-16

...


20000000 <abcd>:
20000000:   0005
```

The gcc solution is less painful as you don't have to hard-code a library path.

Comment: I would like to thank you very much for the effort you put in to the reply, i really appreciate it. This is an amazing and thorough example, i will change my scripts accordingly.

Comment: consider it a minimal reference.  expand as needed.  so far as I know gnu is not one of the compilers that you need to worry about the function called main(), I use a different name for my entry point from prior pain from other compilers.

Comment: if/when you have (may already have) read only/mostly program space (rom/romlike) and read/write memory then .data and .bss either need to be handled in the bootstrap or dont rely on .data and dont assume .bss is zeroed and you can use this minimal example.  most folks will want .data copied and .bss zeroed and you will need work on the linker script too...

Comment: the point here was made by others in comments, but directly, for gnu gcc knows where it is and relative to the location of the binary where to find libgcc.a, ld does not know it needs that info passed in on the command line.  perhaps there is a command line option for ld I dont know as I dont know most of them, but if you examine gccs output when it calls ld you see it provides the -L path and not a magic command line option.

Comment: I have seen others do the inline asm thing instead of a bootstrap, gnu linker warns if _start is not found but that is not fatal by default, just a warning.  I have no issues with your linker script I simply used exising code I had.  .rodata is read only and could go either in rom or ram, rom saves on having to copy it to ram if/when you get to that.  linker scripts are personal works of art just like the application code.